# Relations PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have been having trouble with connecting my Database after I learned more or less how to use Relations. What am trying to do is, make users table a relation to players. Am doing a soccer team website and I want the parents to register(which works, thats the users table) and be able to add their kid out database.
Here are my Tables.

Users Table

```
Column  Type    Null    Default
user_id int(11) No  
username    varchar(32) No  
password    varchar(32) No  
first_name  varchar(32) No  
last_name   varchar(32) No  
email   varchar(1024)   No  
uphone  int(65) No  
pay_received    int(65) No  
pregistered int(65) No  
active  int(11) No  1
type    int(1)  No  0
```

Players Table

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
p_id    int(11) No           
p_name  varchar(65) No           
p_years int(11) No           
team_id int(11) No           
p_under int(11) No           
user_id int(11) No      users -> user_id
```

When I try to add them manually I can, even when it tells me that some items are missing because on the form I only ask for the p_name(name of player) and p_years(years of experience). I try to submit and it does nothing to the players database.

function for the parent to add his son.

```
function register_c($register_c){

    array_walk($register_c, 'array_sanitize');


$cfields = '`' .implode('`, `', array_keys($register_c)) . '`';
$cdata = '\''. implode('\', \'', $register_c) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO players ($cfields, user_id) VALUES ($cdata)");


}
```

Posting after submit button is pressed.

```
<?php

         if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            $register_c = array(
            'p_name' => $_POST['p_name'],
            'p_years' => $_POST['p_years']
            ); 

            register_c($register_c);
            exit();

            } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo output_errors($errors);
            }
            }


?>
```

If anybody could help me that would be great.

Comment: can you primary key pid and userid with auto increment ?

Comment: @AnshulParashar p_id is already primary key as for the user_id in players if i try it it tells me "Query error:
#1832 - Cannot change column 'user_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'players_users_link'"

Comment: Where are you getting your value for user_id in your query from? I think the number of values does not match the number of fields in your query.

Comment: @Rafa579 ones take your query into variable and echo it...then show me what outputs comes